# How do I refresh Mongoose models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The task is:

1. delete all model's documents
2. then save the new model's documents

Something like

```
    Model.remove().then(function () {
        Model.save(new Model({ *some valid data* });
    });
```

It removes all model documents as expected, but the new document doesn't appear, the documents list is empty. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Current Code:**

```
Model.remove().then(function () {
new Model({ *some valid data* }).save();
});
```

`model.save()` creates a promise object. you need to call `.then()` on it for the promise to actually run

**Change to:**

```
Model.remove().then(function () {
new Model({ *some valid data* }).save().then(function () {
// log something here
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the object before applying the save method :

**Javascript**

```
Model.remove().then(function () {
    new Model({ *some valid data* }).save();
});
```

Comment: Yep sorry I forgot parenthesis around 'new Model[..]'

Comment: `(new Model({ *some valid data* })).save();`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the callback or promise to make the query execute. Something like this should work:

```
Model.remove().then(function () {
    var model = new Model({ *some valid data* });
    return model.save();
})
.then(function(result) {
   // Do something with the result
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // Log any errors
});
```